# Covariance of two values

Tags: probability, statistics

A fair die is rolled twice (independently). Let X1 and X2 be the numbers resulting from the first and second rolls, 
respectively. Define Y=X1+X2 and Z=4⋅X1−X2. Find the covariance between Y and Z.

I know that the covariance relates to the expected value...but I'm unsure how to find that as well. Any direction would be helfpul! Thanks!

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758524/covariance-of-sum-and-differences-of-dice-values/758588#758588

Answer (score 0):

Since the rolls are independent and a roll can result in each of the values from 1 to 6 with equal probability 1/6, E(X1) = 1.1/6 + 2.1/6 + ..... + 6.1/6 = 3.5 = E(X2).
Thus, E(Y) = E(X1) + E(X2) = 7 and E(Z) = 4E(X1) - E(X2) = 10.5.
Now, if you right down all possible values of YZ with their corresponding probabilities, you'll arrive at E(YZ) = 82.25.(**)
Also, Cov(X1,X2) = E(X1X2) - E(X1)E(X2), so that we have
Cov(Y,Z) = 82.25 - 7 * 10.5 = 8.75.
This is your required answer.

(**)
However, this might prove to be lengthy and laborious, especially if you are new to it. I may suggest that you calculate Cov(Y,Z) by:
Cov(Y,Z) = Cov(X1+X2,4X1-X2) = 4.Var(X1) + 3.Cov(X1,X2) - Var(X2).
Of course this way you have to calculate the variance and covariance terms involving X1  and X2, but they would not at all be complicated.